# Maven don't execute generate-resources

Tags: maven, unix, filtering

**EDIT**

The problem is the generate-resources goal is not executed by Maven in Unix.
With Maven 2.0.10, I execute that instruction : mvn resources:resources

On windows :

```
[INFO] [dependency:unpack {execution: unpack-filters}]
[INFO] Configured Artifact: com.viaccess.testtools:filters:1.0-SNAPSHOT:jar
[INFO] filters-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar already unpacked.
```

On Unix :

```
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
```

Strange ... Same maven, same conf.

**OLD POST**

I have a problem with filtering my maven project.
It works good on windows, but not on unix (redhat).
Though, maven version is the same, java version is the same and settings.xml of maven is the same. So, I don't see where is the problem.

The maven instruction is mvn clean package
On windows, it works good. On windows, it failed with the error Error loading property file '/var/tmp/test/target/filters/empty.properties'
And not target directory is created.

Somebody can help me ?

More information about the pom files.

Here info about the parent pom :

```
<properties>
    <filters.path>${project.build.directory}/filters</filters.path>
    <filter.default>empty.properties</filter.default>
</properties>

<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>default</id>
    <properties>
        <filter.defaut>default.properties</filter.defaut>
    </properties>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>windows</id>
    <properties>
             <filter.defaut>default.properties</filter.defaut>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
 <resources>
    <resource>
    <directory>filters</directory>
      <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/filters</targetPath>
    </resource>
  </resources>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>unpack-filters</id>
        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>unpack</goal>
        </goals>  
        <configuration>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>com.viaccess.testtools</groupId>
              <artifactId>filters</artifactId>
              <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
              <includes>*.properties</includes>
              <outputDirectory>${filters.path}</outputDirectory>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

The filter project is like that :

```
<build>
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/filters</directory>
    <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/classes</targetPath>
    <includes>
      <include>*.properties</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>
</build>
```

And the main project is like that.

```
<parent>
    <!-- link to my parent project -->
</parent>

  <build>
    <filters>
      <filter>${filters.path}/${filter.defaut}</filter>
    </filters>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the spelling of `filter.defaut` intented?

Comment: @Torsten I don't understand what you said. What do you mean with intented ? The problem is the unpack goal is nt launched in Unix

Comment: filter.defaut is misspelled in the profile.  (missing the 'l' in default)

Comment: Update as soon as possible the Maven version your are using.

Comment: @user944849 Yep, it's a mistake in the post. I have translated the name "defaut" in English (to "default") but not in all elements.
The problem is the unpack goal is not launched

Comment: @khmarbaise I have the same problem with new version of maven

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. No problem on the pom, a problem of nexus.
On windows, I used the last pom parent beacause it's my work desktop (and I make a pom install).
Unix is a remote server. The downloading of the pom parent was already done, so new version was never uploaded.

Noob problem, sorry ... :)

Thanks for your help.

Eric